# Mailgun unsubscribe url can't be reached

Tags: mailgun

So I am currently handling a mailgun account with multiple domains.
Whenever I include the `%unsubscribe_url%` to the mail body and opens up the generated url, I'm having this `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` error.
the generated url has domain `email.mg.domain.com`.

But we have this one specific mailgun domain that has a working unsubscribe url, the url links to a working webpage with domain `link.mailgun.com` and was able to unsub without problem.

Also changing the domain in the browser from `email.mg.domain.com` to `link.mailgun.com` makes it work.

I don't know what's the issue here on why their unsubscribe url has different domains. I've looked at their domain settings in mailgun dashboard and they seem to be identical.

Thanks!